# Javascript -How remove item from nested object?

Tags: javascript, ecmascript-6

I'm trying to remove an item from a nested object. object named "categories" that contains several categories and each category has several businesses. something like bellow object:

```
let categories = [{
  name: 'Home',
  biz: [{
    name: 'Business 1',
    id: 50
  }, {
    name: 'Business 2',
    id: 52
  }, {
    name: 'Business n',
    id: 53
  }]
}, {
  name: 'Car',
  biz: [{
    name: 'Business 1',
    id: 62
  }, {
    name: 'Business 2',
    id: 66
  }, {
    name: 'Business n',
    id: 67
  }]
}];
```

What I'm trying to do is removing one of this businesses that selected by user and return the whole object without mutating original state.

so far I did something like bellow and it's working fine bu I'm not sure if I'm doing this the right way or the wrong way. I appreciate if you guys help me by review or refactor this code:

```
categories.map((cat, inedx) => {
  return { ...cat, biz: [...cat.biz.filter(bz => bz.id!== 66)]}
});
```

Comment: No need for the `[...array]` otherwise its fine.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

reduce to the rescue :-)

```
const fn = (categories, id) => {
  return categories.reduce((r, x) => {
    return r.concat({ ...x, biz: x.biz.filter(x => x.id !== id) });
  }, []);
}

console.log(fn(categories, 66));
```

Comment: EDIT: this is minimal example, you also would like to add some type checks (e.g. is x.biz array? etc).

Comment: I always get confused when I want to use this method :-)

Comment: been there :-) when you do a lot of practices, it will sit in your mind, no worries.

Answer (score 0):

```js
    let categories = [{
        name: 'Home',
        biz: [{
            name: 'Business 1',
            id: 50
        }, {
            name: 'Business 2',
            id: 52
        }, {
            name: 'Business n',
            id: 53
        }]
    }, {
        name: 'Car',
        biz: [{
            name: 'Business 1',
            id: 62
        }, {
            name: 'Business 2',
            id: 66
        }, {
            name: 'Business n',
            id: 67
        }]
    }];

categories.forEach(el => el.biz = el.biz.filter(e => e.id !== 66));

    console.log("removed  biz 66", categories)
```

Comment: This solution is returning a whole new object every time. When the request was “without mutating the original”  object

Comment: without return "whole new object"